# tablesorter select box with a custom match function

Tags: html, tablesorter

I have an HTML table with a column, in which an unordered list of strings is present. I am using tablesorter with the filter plugin to interact with the list. I want each string in all cells of the column to be present in a select filter in the header of the table. If the user selects an option, those rows should be displayed, where this string appears in the unordered list of the particular column cell.

Let me give you an example. I have the following list:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>profession</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Carl</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Builder</li>
                    <li>Professor</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lisa</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Programmer</li>
                    <li>Professor</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the table header, I want tablesorter to display a select box with the three professions. If, say, `professor` is selected, both rows should be shown. If `programmer` is selected, only Lisa would appear. How would I reach that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`filter_functions` widget option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-functions) as follows ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3072/)):

```
$(function () {

    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_functions: {
                1: {
                    "Programmer": function (e, n) { return /programmer/.test(n); },
                    "Professor" : function (e, n) { return /professor/.test(n); },
                    "Builder"   : function (e, n) { return /builder/.test(n); } 
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

---

Update: If you don't want to hardcode because the professions vary, then you can use the [`filter_selectSource` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource) to grab all of the column text, extract out each item from the list then return it as an array ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3080/)):

HTML (make sure to include these class names)

```
<th class="filter-select filter-match">profession</th>
```

Script

```
$(function () {

    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_selectSource: function (table, column, onlyAvail) {
                // get an array of all table cell contents for a table column
                var arry = [],
                    array = $.tablesorter.filter.getOptions(table, column, onlyAvail);
                // split content if multiple professions are encountered
                $.each( array, function(i, n){
                    // look for carriage returns; split into two separate professions
                    if (/\n/.test(n)) {
                        n = n.split(/\n/);
                    }
                    arry.push(n);
                });
                // flatten array
                return $.map(arry, function(n){ return n; });
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi Mottie, thank you! However, this would require me to hardcode the options into the js file. However, I want to populate the select box with alle those professions, that appear as `<li>` items in any of the columns' cells.

Comment: That's it. Thank's for the great support and for being on SO. :)

Comment: For future reference, the code is slightly different if you want to [extract items from a nested table](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3081/). All of these demos have been added to the [home wiki page](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki#widgets) of the repository.