# Tablesorter Filter with multiple "values" in cell

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter

I'm using tablesorter with Filter widget but i have a problem with the filter.

I'm using filter-select class in the header and it's working fine.

Problem is i have the cells in which there can be more than 1 data, but filter is getting the text all togheter instead of each value separate.

Just to be clear:

```
<tr>
    <td>John Wayne</td>
    <td>
            <div class="rip">Riplet</div>
            <div class="rip">Pipe</div>
    </td>
<tr>
```

The fitler select appears with 1 option like this "RipletPipe", but i need it to be 2 options "Riplet" and "Pipe".

I've tried with functions etc but I don't seem to get to it.

Main problem is I think that the data in the "multiple value cell" is dynamic.

Please help me :)

Comment: This is very similar to a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193481/tablesorter-select-box-with-a-custom-match-function) asking about how to extract out values from a list. Essentially use the new [`filter_selectSource` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource).

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed Mottie. Btw great plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Motties help I achieved what I needed.

I'm posting my solution for future use for users needing something similar.

```
filter_selectSource: function (table, column, onlyAvail) {
        var arry = [];

            tds = $(table).find('tbody tr').find('td:eq('+column+')');

            tds.find('.rip').each(function(i,n){
                arry.push($(this).text());
            });

        return $.map(arry, function(n){ return n; });
 }
```

I guess this code can be optimized but for now it works and it's ok for me.

To make sure filtering works you need to add `filter-match` to the header else it will search for exact value and it won't find the rows.

Comment: Nice! Just so you know, there is a built-in function to get all the text from the column: `$.tablesorter.filter.getOptions(table, column, onlyAvail);` (from the [`filter_selectSource` docs](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#widget-filter-selectsource)). This function returns an array

Comment: I tried that Mottie, but it's giving me the whole text as one (for the example above "RipletPipe" without any carriage returns or so instead of 2 items in the array, so I couldn't split it up in 2. Maybe I was doing something wrong thou.

Comment: Ahh ok, if you look in the updated code in the link I shared, it grabs all of the code from the table cell, then splits it up `n = n.split(/\n/);`. Either way, you got a solution that works, so no problem.